# Javascript - get class of another element with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I want to individually toggle to different divs using the same function. Each of these divs has a common class and a different id. The function `toggle` is called using an onclick parameter on two separate `<a>` elements:

```
<a class="btn" id="btnOne" onclick="toggler();">Show/hide divOne</a>
<div class="box" id="divOne">

<a class="btn" id="btnTwo" onclick="toggler();">Show/hide divTwo</a>
<div class="box" id="divTwo">
```

I first tried to get these divs with getElementsByClassName but, as it returns an HTMLCollection, the script can't target each div individually.

So I tried to select the `<a>` tags ids (btnOne and btnTwo), but couldn't figure out how to retrieve the divs class using these ids (as we're talking about two different elements here).

In the end, I came back to the getElementById method, as I couldn't figure out how to select them based on their class:

```
function toggler() {
    var id = document.getElementById("divId");
    if (id.style.display === "none") {
        id.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        id.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

This leaves me with two functions instead of just one. Any suggestion on how to target the two divs individually?

Comment: Why don't you just send some parameters to the function? `onclick="toggler('divOne');"`

Comment: Use 'getElementsByClassName('box')[0]' to get the first element with that classname, use getElementsByClassName('box')[1] to get the last element.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak but how can I do this if I want to have more than two toggable divs?

Comment: The index can be used to access the element, just change the [index] to what you want.

Comment: @PoulBak I don't want to have to edit my function for each div. I want want function that automatically targets the div corresponding to the <a> tag that's above it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @ritaj. But how do I get it in the script afterwards? something like this: `function ibToggler(theClass) { if (theClass.style.display === "none")...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the next sibling using `nextElementSibling` presuming the box will always be right after the hyperlink.

```js
// Put the buttons into an array
const buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName("btn")];
// Assing an event listener for every button
buttons.map(button => button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Find the next sibling
  const box = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  // Toggle the display value
  if (box.style.display === "none") {
    box.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    box.style.display = "none";
  }
}));
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">Show/hide divOne</a>
<div class="box"></div>

<a class="btn">Show/hide divTwo</a>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gerard. This works amazingly. I'd also like to hide the boxes again when the user clicks anywhere else than on the box itself. I tried adding something like `e.target.nextElementSibling.closest()` to the if statement but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Any additional suggestion on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to select the divs with their class name and you already used it.
The answer is `getElementsByClassName`. But in vanilla JS things are a little bit (over)complicated.
It will not target both divs individually. Instead, if you want to select the first div with this class you would do it like this:

```
getElementsByClassName('classname')[0]
```

If you want to select the second div you would use:

```
getElementsByClassName('classname')[1]
```

and so on. But there is a way of course.
You want to use loops:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
   } else {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

In this way, you will target ALL divs with this class.

Comment: As stated in my question, I want to target the divs with this class individually, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd dynamically add the events on the switches, using their classes. I added the class `showHideDivBtn` to them. To make sure you know which div you have to toggle, I used a `data-id`.

With addEventListener, I can use the event variable I named `e`. With this one, I have access to properties, such as the `data-id` I wrote.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("showHideDivBtn");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i)
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        let divToToggle = document.getElementById(e.srcElement.dataset.id);
        if (divToToggle.style.display === "none")
            divToToggle.style.display = "block";
        else
            divToToggle.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

```html
<a class="btn showHideDivBtn" data-id="divOne" id="btnOne">Show/hide divOne</a>
<div class="box" id="divOne">One</div>
<br />
<a class="btn showHideDivBtn" data-id="divTwo" id="btnTwo">Show/hide divTwo</a>
<div class="box" id="divTwo">Two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substr to get the word after extracting 'btn' from anchor id which will result in One or Two then while defining the if use "div"+word this will get the div by it is related a tag

```
function toggler() {
    var word=this.id.substr(3);
    var id = document.getElementById("div"+word);
    if (id.style.display === "none") {
    id.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    id.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```